Can I switch the garbage disposal?
I would like to move the garbage disposal to the bigger, lower sink on the right.  Would this be possible based on my setup? I would also be willing to buy a smaller compact disposal, if necessary.  If so, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to set it up.


FWIW, I agree that the disposal belongs on the soak/wash sink rather than the rinse sink, if at all possible. It may in fact be worth investing in redoing the wall plumbing if that's what is needed to make this happen.

Although I know that is standard, based on the setup of my kitchen, I personally would prefer the disposal on the deeper/bigger sink.   Also, this is probably a relatively short term adjustment, we plan on renovating the kitchen in a couple years and when we do, I would get just a single big bowl.

Exactly Joule!  Soak shmoak.  Two sinks are the one that is always full of disgusting old dishes, and the other one.

The exit from the disposal has to be above the trap arm.  It is right now, measurement "B" below.   You are going to lose measurement "A".   Will it still be higher?
Note: The trap arm is the part the comes out of the wall, at the rightmost end of the yellow line in my pic.  The BOTTOM of the exit from the disposal should be higher than the TOP of the trap arm.   Take measurement B that way.
If it's not higher, a compact disposal may solve the problem, but don't assume.   Look at the documentation for precise measurements and compare to your old one.
If it still doesn't work, you can lower the trap arm by breaking open the back wall.   It's not a cheap job, but since it's in the back of a cabinet you don't have to redecorate it nicely.  If you're having a plumber install the disposal, it would probably add an hour of labor and a few cheap parts to lower it.   (Unless you're in a big city high rise ... then forget it.  Ignore this paragraph entirely.)

Approximate arrangement:

The red circled parts can be bought in a kit.  For the smaller sink you may need to buy either a longer piece or an extender.  Take both pictures to the store and ask for help.  Watch YouTube "how to install disposal" videos.  If you reuse the one you should buy a new gasket.

Thanks so much! Really appreciate it.  Took the measurement and the bottom of the disposal outtake would only be about 0.5 in above the top of the trap arm.  Found a newer/quieter disposal that would be it about 1.5 in above.  Would that be enough?

BTW, would greatly appreciate any suggestion on how the plumbing to make this switch would be set up.

Joule I added a photo for guidance to the answer.  You may need to adapt it slightly.    If you're going to renovate later do not move the trap arm now because the new position may not be what you want in the renovation.  0.5 in is probably not great.  Try it. If it drains poorly then get the smaller one.  You'll become an expert at installing disposals. :)

Thanks so much for the suggestions.  I'll definitely give this a try...once I find the time haha
